# what is user agent Whirlpool BD2; H010818

Tags: user-agent

what is this user agent

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; H010818)

this came from a ip address tracing to the organisation Websense

the question also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/264633/what-is-user-agent-whirlpool-bd2-h010818)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not an Internet-connected Refrigerator Browser?

Whirlpool make something like that in 2k.

See also:

> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows 98; Whirlpool BD2)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows 98; Whirlpool BD2; FunWebProducts)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; FunWebProducts)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows 98; Whirlpool BD2)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows 98; Whirlpool BD2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows 98; Whirlpool BD2; YComp 5.0.0.0
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows 98; Whirlpool Std 6)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool BD2; H010818)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool Std 6)
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool Std 6; (R1 1.5))
>
> Browser Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Whirlpool Std 6; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)